# How much is the total cost for each town hall level

Tags: clash-of-clans

after spending a bunch of time farming resources, I'm at level 8 TH, with 40 level 8 walls (maxed) and the rest at level 7, farming each day 2M of gold, 40 max walls at this TH is 20M, so more than 10 days of farming to never have an idle constructor.

So this question came to my mind.

**Have anyone ever calculated how much it cost for a full upgrade at each town hall level?**

I try to max everything but collectors before upgrading my TH and would be nice to know how much time will take to max everything.

To clear it out:

My question is, if I level my TH having all other building maxed, how much it will cost to max everything else but TH? including walls and can exclude collectors.

Answer (score 3):

According to this ["link"](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Cumulative_Costs)

At town hall 8 ( assumed you just upgraded to level 8 ) :

- canon : 5x (800K+1600K) = 12,000,000
- archer tower : 4x (1500K+2500K) + 1x ( level 1 to 10 ) = 21,368,000
- Mortar : 4x= 6,400,000
- wizard tower : 3x = 16,460,000
- Air defense : 3x = 8,482,500
- Hidden tesla : 3x = 26,250,000
- Elixir storage : 1x =948,550
- Clan castle : 1x = 1,800,000

Total cost for defenses = 95,109,050 golds

walls level 8 : 225x = 128,560,000 - 40x ( already level 8) = 108,560,000

Comment: there are new buildings now

Answer (score -1):

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall

This link will tell you how much gold is required for each respective town hall level

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is not what I asked, editing the question.